# How to set the generic type of an ArrayList at runtime in java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Ok, so I am setting up my own XML serialization (I know there are others out there, even some built in to Java, but I am doing it myself to learn and because it is so awesome to work with). I have serialization down. I am currently on the deserialization (reading in the XML file and assembling objects based on the data in the file) and I am running into problems with setting generic types. After extensive research, I figured out how to get the generic types of a class so I could write them when serializing, but I have no clue how to do this:

```
Class c = Class.forName(string);
ArrayList<c> list = new ArrayList<c>();
```

I have seen a few answers for this in C#, but obviously C# is a bit more versatile than Java, and there is no way that I can replicate the solutions there in Java. Can this even be done, even with reflection?

Comment: You can't. Generics are simply compile time syntactic sugar.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yeah ... most of the time I just feel like it probably needs a far better explanation than I want to type at this time of night :) But I"ll bite - moved to answer.

Comment: You can't. The question doesn't make sense. Generics are a compile-time mechanism that is erased by the compiler. The total effect at runtime is zero. So even if you could do it nothing would change as a result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't.

Generics in Java are simply compile-time syntactic sugar. It makes it so you don't have to cast everything to and from `Object` like we did in the old days when dinosaurs roamed the JVM, and gives you some compile-time type checking.

**Edit to add:** There is *some* metadata preserved at runtime that you can get at via reflection to *inspect* a generic class, but nothing like what you want.

Comment: Oh drive-by-downvoter, please do tell. Or have I once again hurt someone's feelings on the internet?

Comment: Is there any way to do what I am trying to do at all? I have a string representing a type, and I want to come out with an `ArrayList<that type>`. Is there any way to make that happen?

Comment: No hurt feelings: I just think your answer was misleading, even with the qualification, so I voted it down.

Comment: @Daniel - And what, exactly, is misleading or incorrect? Please, indulge me.

Comment: @jchitel - To do what you want you can't use generics. You can cast to/from `Object` (everything in Java is a subclass of `Object`) and not use generics. Actually ... are you wanting to store the class or an *instance* of the class?

Comment: @BrianRoach so if I have an `ArrayList<Object>` I can just cast it to an `ArrayList<whatever>` later when I have the type?

Comment: Sorry - edited my last comment too late; are you trying to store instances of that class, or the class itself in that `ArrayList`?

Comment: I have no problem storing. My problem is with retrieving. I have an `ArrayList` whose contents, including the generic parameter type, are stored in a file. I want to read in that generic parameter type and be able to set that as the generic parameter of a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yeah, not so much. You can't do that. I'm trying to think of how you can even do that with casting and am coming up short, but it's late and I've had a few beers (sorry).

Comment: @BrianRoach I think we should regard unexplained downvotes as a veiled compliment: the sincerest form of flattery on SO.

Comment: @jchitel - I mean - if you don't need it to be *completely* dynamic (as in, you have a finite set of types), you can create a factory that creates the right thing based on the string.

Comment: @BrianRoach Well actually if I have the Field then I should just be able to use the type of that Field to create a new instance with all the right generic parameters right? I mean, other serializers have to have some way around this problem.

Comment: Nope. No generic typing at runtime; it's all erased. The best you could do is know in advance what type you *might* have and create them via a factory. e.g. `Factory.createList(String foo)` where in that factory it has `if (foo.equals("Bar")) { return new ArrayList<Bar>(); } `

Comment: I find calling generics "simply compile-time syntactic sugar" misleading in a couple of ways. I think it implies that no type-checking occurs with generics (I'd imagine you don't think that, I just think "syntactic sugar" is a bad choice of wording).

Comment: I think your answer also downplays the type information that is retained, for example the type parameters of fields. That kind of information is relevant and useful in cases like this: e.g. Deserialising a list field that contains numbers from XML, you can inspect the type being deserialised, see that its field is List<Integer>, and coalesce the string numbers from the XML to Integers. I'm sorry if I upset you: I just thought your answer could have been better.

Comment: Oh .. you mean *the last part of the same sentence that says exactly that* isn't clear enough? Either way ... whatever, since it has *nothing to do with his question*. Not upset, just amused by people who not only don't post answers, nitpick things.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set generic type at runtime.
All generic type information is erased at compile time.

See below articles to understand type erasure:

[Type Erasure StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

[Type Erasure Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Answer (score 0):

else what you can do (if you have limited number of classes).. you make a check of object by using 'instance of' operator and depending upon that place that in your arraylist

```
if(obj instance of abc)
    ArrayList<abc> al = new ArrayList<abc>();
```

you can have nested if else or switch

Answer (score 0):

No, Generics is only at compile time, only for compile-time type checking, to allow you to avoid casts that can be proven safe at compile-time.

Think about it. If you could do what you want, it would be completely useless. The whole point of having `ArrayList<String>`, say, is that when you get an element out of it, the compiler can infer at compile-time that it has type `String`, and so it allows you to assign it to type `String` in the code without a cast. Also, if you try to add an element into it, the compiler can check at compile-time that it is of type `String`, or else not let you do it.

But you want a type parameter that is not known at compile-time. Thus when you get an element out of it, the compiler doesn't know anything about its type, so you can only assign it to type `Object`. And when you try to put something into it, the compiler doesn't know what type it's supposed to allow, so it must allow all types? Then there is no point to the generics.

Thus, you should just use the upper bound type as the type parameter. Like `ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();`